# How to filter categories of a post

Tags: posts, categories

Is there any way to filter the categories of a post? I am using `wp_get_post_categories( $post -> ID );`
i want to filter this listing i.e. `if(post_name or post_id == "some id or some name") {it should not be displayed}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried something like,

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post -> ID  );

foreach($post_categories as $c){
    $cat = get_category( $c );
    if ( $cat->slug != "cat" ) {
       echo "$cat->name";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [in_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category):

```
$post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );

foreach( $post_categories as $cat_id ) {
    if ( in_category( $cat_id, POST_ID ) ) {
        // it should not be displayed
    } else {
        // it should be displayed
    }
}
```

Where `POST_ID` should be the ID of the post wich you want to check.